# Regex and newline pattern

Tags: php, regex, function, quote

I have a function:

```
function ColoredQuote($string) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('/>.+/', '<span class=quote>$0</span><br />', $string);
    return $buffer;
}
```

And it works great when there is a simple string only i'd like to format. But I want to make this function working only when the string with > mark is after a new line and when there is second new line mark at the end of it. I also want to prevent space right after the > mark. I was trying adding \n, the ^ mark and other that might be helpful but it's not working.

So the pattern should looks like:

```
[br]>any text[br]
```

This is popular quoting method on imageboards

Answer (score 0):

To replace all lines beginning with `>` alter your regexp to this:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/^>.+$/', '<span class=quote>$0</span><br />', $string);
```

`^` means start of the line
`$` means end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it by myself, so for anyone who will find it useful:

```
function ColoredQuote($string) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('!\>\S.+!', '<br /><span class=quote>$0</span><br />', $string);
    return $buffer;
    }
```